# Get real classpath when running java application with mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven, classpath

My java application needs to access the classpath via `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`. This works perfect when I run the application from IDE. However if I run the application with maven via `mvn exec:java`, I found the classpath returned is always `/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar`.

Question is how can I get my real classpath when the app started by `mvn exec:java`?

Updates: I end up calling `URLClassLoader.getURLs()` to get the classpath

Comment: You can't, because `exec:java` is intended to run from within Maven. `exec:exec` will do what you want, but I'm not writing that as an answer because reading `java.class.path` is a bad idea (as you've seen, it is different depending on how you're invoked). What is the *real* problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

the hint in your update worked for me. here's my implementation for my fork of `kilim.tools.Javac`, ie a wrapper around `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`

```
static String getClassPath() {
    String cp = "";
    ClassLoader sys = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    ClassLoader cl = Javac.class.getClassLoader();
    for (; cl != null & cl != sys; cl = cl.getParent())
        if (cl instanceof java.net.URLClassLoader) {
            java.net.URLClassLoader ucl = (java.net.URLClassLoader) cl;
            for (java.net.URL url : ucl.getURLs())
                cp += File.pathSeparator + url.getPath();
        }
    return cp.length()==0 ? null : cp.substring(1);
}
```

the result get's passed to the compiler as `compiler.run(null, null, null, arg1, arg2, "-cp", getClassPath())`